# Different version of Intersect() in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

There is a `User` entity and I have a list of `User` objects. `User` entity looks like this :

```
public class User{

public int Id {get; set;}

public List<Group> Groups {get; set;}

}
```

And Group class looks like this :

```
public class Group{

public int Id {get; set;}

public string GroupName {get; set;}

}
```

Finally I have a list of string which is like this :

```
List<string> GroupNames;
```

I have a list of `User` objects. I want to pick User objects whose Groups contain a Group object which has their name inside the list GroupNames. 
For example, if GroupNames contain NYC, Chicago, Seattle, I want to pick Users whose Groups' GroupName equals to any of these cities. In code It looks like this :

```
List<string> GroupNames = new List<string> { "NYC", "Chicago","Seattle"};

var filteredUsers = Users.Where(x => x.Groups....)// I don't know what to write in this query.
```

Can you help me write this query? I appreciate any help, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linq should slove this easy by combining `Any()` with `Contains()`

```
var filteredUsers = Users.Where(x => x.Groups.Any(y => GroupNames.Contains(y.GroupName)));
```

Comment: Can this query be used inside an Async method?

Comment: @jason yes sure it can

Comment: I get this error in my code : `Enumerable.Any method is not supported`. Can I do this without `Any` method? Thanks a lot.

Comment: did you add `using System.Linq` ?

Comment: I'm getting this error in my AsyncRun method. There is no query in that.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using `Any()` and `Contains()`:

```
var filteredUsers = Users.Where(t => t.Groups.Any(q => GroupNames.Contains(q.GroupName));
```

This is almost identical to fubo's answer.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is using the `Intersect()` + `Any()` (but note the use of `.Select(x => x.GroupName)` to select only the `GroupName`)

```
var filteredUsers = Users.Where(x => x.Groups.Select(x => x.GroupName).Intersect(GroupNames).Any());
```